# NSString automatic font size

Tags: ios, nsstring, core-graphics, cgcontext

Possible duplicate.
I use drawInRect method of string. How can I find font size that fits in specified rect? For example if used a font with size 16 and I tried draw it in 10x10 rect, then string is disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the size of your text with a font, use this:

```
float s = [myFont fontWithSize:25];
```

With this size, you can compare it with the size of your rectangle and check if it's bigger

Comment: I want to know maximal font size that can fit to specified rect. Max string length is two characters. Font size is depends on rect size and string with this font shouldn't be draw outside rect

Answer (score 0):

Use `CGSize size = [yourString sizeWithFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]]` until you reach a size, that is smaller than needed.